# How to find the modulation index of an amplitude modulated signal from the spectrum analyser?

Tags: matlab, spectrum, amplitude-modulation

My aim to is compute the modulation index(u) of a amplitude modulated waveform but I only have access to its power spectrum from the spectrum analyser.

I attached an image from the spectrum analyser.

[image: Power spectrum analyser]

(Note: The spectrum analyser has an input impedance of 50 ohms).

The carrier has a power of -26.6 dBm and the two sidebands have power of -38.5 dBm each.

Quite obviously we know the modulation index must be less than 1 because the carrier has more power - but how do I find the exact modulation index?

**My thought process:**

1. First I converted the dBm to watts.
2. Then I found the voltage using P=(V^2)/R, for carrier and sidebands and we know R would be like 50.
3. Then I just did modulation index= mp/Ac where mp is the voltage in the message signal and Ac is the voltage in the carrier signal which is computed in step 2.

After doing all this I get a u of 0.25. This sounds kind of correct but what do you guys think?

```
***clear;clearvars;clc;clearAllMemoizedCaches

m_db= -38.5 ; % message power dBm

mpow= (10^(m_db/10))/1000 % message power in watts

c_db= -26.6;  % carrier power dBm

cpow=(10^(c_db/10))/1000  % carrier power in watts

mv= sqrt(mpow*50) % message voltage

cv= sqrt(cpow*50) % carrier voltage

mu= mv/cv % modulation index= message/carrier
```

Comment: you need to know your message signal's spectrum, otherwise: no chance.

Comment: Reply to Marcus, I know the message signal has a frequency of 64kHz but I don't know the voltage of it. Its power is -38.5 dBm in each sideband. Is that enough info?

Comment: Well, you know the spectrum/power of the message signal, or of the modulated signal? If only the modulated signal: not sufficient, the modulation index tells us exactly how the relationship between message signal PSD and unsuppressed carrier is.

Comment: Isn't the modulated signal the same as message?

Comment: no. That's the point of a modulation index: you got the carrier coming through, and the modulation index tells you how much, in the end. Different message signals subject to  different modulation indices lead to the same RF spectrum. Back to comment 1!

Comment: ok I think its the difference in terminology which is causing confusion. Modulation index by definition is Am/Ac where Am is message and Ac is carrier peak amplitude voltage. (My university teachers use the terms message and modulated signal interchangeably but I think you are referring to the modulated signal as the signal after modulation is performed?)  So you think  modulation index can't be found just by the spectrum analyser? If so, then lemme try and find some more info. (Also, I know that is pure AM not PAM message signal is a sine wave at 64kHz  but don't know amplitude)

Comment: (Also thanks to Marcus for his comments, I appreciate you trying to help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modulation index is commonly defined as the ratio of peak voltages; the peak voltage of the message signal per the peak voltage of the carrier. Index >1 causes distortion in envelope detectors, but not in synchronous demodulation.

There's comments which try to explain that unfortunately you cannot derive the time domain message signal from your coarse spectrum. You must know or guess it otherwise.

If the message happens to be sinusoidal you have already successfully calculated that the sideband peak voltage divided by the carrier peak voltage is 0.25

But there are 2 sidebands which both have 50% of the peak voltage of the signal sinewave. Thus the modulation index is 0.5

If the message is not a pure sinewave the case is complex. Do the resolution bandwidth even cover the sidebands or not? impossible to decide from the given data.  I'm afraid you must make a reference measurement and find the message amplitude which generates the same spectrum with the same analyzer settings. You, of course, must have the message signal available.

Comment: Thanks for this! I think you've help me solve this conundrum. I know the message signal is defo a pure sine wave (not triangle or pulse stream) but its amplitude I don't know. The resolution bandwidth(RBW) is small and it covers the sidebands I'm being told, the RBW is not big so it doesn't obscure the harmonics insides. That part about the side bands having half of the message voltage is key I think because I didn't know that before.